# Error 1064 in procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(sele
>   ct ifnull(count(tbl_Product.manufactureId),0)
>                   from tbl_product where manu' at line 5

```
create procedure ManufactureCheckForDelete(p_manufactureid varchar(50))
begin
    declare p_id longtext ;
    declare p_result longtext;
    set p_id (select ifnull(count(tbl_Product.manufactureId),0)
        from tbl_product where manufactureId = p_manufactureId 
    ) ;

    if p_id <> 0 then
    set p_result = 'true' ;
    else
    set p_result = 'false' ;
    end if ;

    select p_result ;
end
```

Comment: Probably the worst question title ever

Comment: Question title isn't very clear. Try being specific.

Comment: Where is the *=* operator? `set p = (...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use = operator to assign the result from query

```
set p_id (select ifnull(count(tbl_Product.manufactureId),0)
        ^^ here
        from tbl_product where manufactureId = p_manufactureId 
    ) ;

set p_id= (select ifnull(count(tbl_Product.manufactureId),0)
        ^^ here
        from tbl_product where manufactureId = p_manufactureId 
    ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks .. u have eagle eyes.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your error says you have a space in `select`

> ...syntax to use near '**(sele ct** ifnull...

And you are missing a `=` before the select.

```
set p_id = (select ...
         ^-------------here
```

Comment: Well the error says different. You can retype that part of your query. Maybe a hidden special character got in the way

Comment: The space verly likely comes from verbatim copy and paste of the error message. So it shouldn't be the real error source.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same name for table in your request, you use

> tbl_Product

and

> tbl_product

Change your request to

```
select ifnull(count(tbl_product.manufactureId),0)
    from tbl_product where manufactureId = p_manufactureId
```